# What to do with a response object returned from a service?

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I am calling a service which inserts some data into a table. In my code I have a flag to insert the data if it is true and in case of false it inserts the data using a normal `JDBCTemplate` class. Since I am new to calling REST services I am a little unsure on what to do with my response object. Currently I am just checking for the response messages and catching exception. As a client do I need to do more than that or is it enough by just checking the messages because the service will insert the data so I don't have to do anything else.

I want to know if the below code makes sense the way I've coded it. Here `wsAuditClient.add( request );` I am calling the service.

```
public void insertRecord( final WSTO to ) {
    boolean isWriteEnabled = true;

    if( isWriteEnabled ) {
        String appCode = ( String ) AppContext.getBean( Constants.SPRING_BEANCODE );
        WSRequest request = wsAuditClient.getWSRequest();
        WSAudit entity = new WSAudit();

        WSRecord record = new WSRecord();
        record.setCode( appCode );
        record.setCallType( "???" );
        record.setContent( "???" );
        record.setServiceName( to.getWsName() );
        record.setServiceTransactionId( to.getServiceTransactionId() );
        entity.addRecord( record );

        request.setEntity( entity );
        request.setAccepts( ContentType.JSON );

        WSResponse response = wsAuditClient.add( request );
        if ( response != null ) {
            List<Message> messages = response.getMessages();

            if ( messages != null && messages.size() > 0 ) {
                for ( Message message : messages ) {
                    if ( MessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR.equals( message.getMessageType() ) ) {
                        throw new Exception( "WS Add call returned with error (code=" + message.getMessageCode() + ", text=" + message.getMessageText() + ")" );
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new CoreException( "WS Add call returned with no messages" );
            }
        }

    } else {
        getJdbcTemplate().update( getSQLStatement( "wsAuditInsert" ), new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
          ps.setString( 1, to.getWsName() );
          ps.setString( 2, to.getDetails() );
          ps.setString( 3, to.getServiceTransactionId() );
          new DefaultLobHandler().getLobCreator().setClobAsString( ps, 4, to.getXml() );
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: How should your app respond if the service fails?

Comment: Andrew, could you please explain in detail so that I get more idea and in a high level do you think my code looks good on what I am trying to achieve in terms of inserting data.

Comment: If the service is responsible for inserting the data why would your app insert it? Code review is off topic for SO, but most of the code within the public method should be delegated to private methods.

Comment: Actually I will delete the else part that is whyI got the flag just to make sure the service is working. What about the response object? I am just checking for the return messages.Thanks for your time Andrew.

Comment: Seems reasonable - interrogate the response to ensure the service was successful.

Comment: Cool, thanks Andrew.